# Where can I find my referral code?

Tags: rage-of-bahamut

In *Rage of Bahamut*, you receive a nice bonus when a friend signs up using your referral code.

There's just one small problem. **I can't find my referral code!** I've checked every screen I could find (even the FAQ), and was unsuccessful. A quick Google search brought back nothing but "lololol use my referral code XD !!1!1" That's considerably unhelpful.

**How do I find my referral code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions:

1. Go to `My Page`
2. Scroll down to image `Invite a friend - Get Dark Knight`
3. Then choose `Get Referral Code`

Hope this helps.

You can also find it using the "Post on Twitter" link.  It generates a message with your referral code.

Comment: Wow... Never would've found that...

Comment: The name of the card you'll get is actually MUCH larger than the text, and the card isn't always Dark Knight. My friend saw "Invite a friend - Get Magic Librarian"